# Rendering a table in a word file (doc file)

Tags: java, html, html-table, birt, doc

I am displaying a table in an HTML page. I want to display those data in a word file and I want to download it from the webpage.

How do I generate a Doc file with tables?

What are the options available to me? BIRT or any other simple options?

Comment: Apache poi is always nice. Does it have to be doc or can it be odt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do this is if you use free Apache POI library.

Link: http://poi.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

I've used Jasper Reports for a while. This allows you to create pdf, doc, xls etc. by use of different data sources such as database or JTable and there are more than these. Design once with its GUI program than create any type of document with any type of data source..